# Generating a logical vector from two numeric vectors - R

Tags: r, vector, logical-operators

I'm very new to R and having difficulty trying to generate a logical vector c from two numeric vectors a and b of the same (arbitrary) size where c contains either TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the corresponding elements of vector b are multiples of a.

Ex.

```
    a<-c(2,3)
    b<-c(6,14)
```

result c is TRUE, FALSE

This is what I've got thus far:

```
    a<-c(2:10)
    b<-c(6:14)
    c<-(if(b%%a) as.integer(TRUE))
```

I realize that the `if()` function is not vectorized and will only evaluate the first element, however, I'm thoroughly confounded and have not been able to see figure out any other construction with any successes. Any insight, links, or guidance would be most helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
c <- ( b%%a == 0 )
```

(The parentheses are optional, only included for clarity.)