# create logical vector in r from values in another vector

Tags: r, vector

being new to R im having some issues creating the following vector:

Create the logical vector `ww` which elements are `TRUE` if the elements of `v1`
#' are larger or equal to 3 and `FALSE` otherwise

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529927/generating-a-logical-vector-from-two-numeric-vectors-r?rq=1) is close to being a duplicate - the solution looks helpful

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below

```
ww <- v1 >=3
```